# WebElement click obstructed by another WebElement in Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I cannot click the `WebElement` (button), because it is hidden by the circle. (overlay)

How to click the button?

[image]

**Note-001** The circle element **CAN** be moved. I can move the circle, but sometimes it comes behind the button.

**Note-002:** I do not want to use the JavaScript button click function. (`JavascriptExecutor` /`.executeScript()`/`.execute()`)

How to know when the circle is behind the button?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
public void foo(){
  try{
     button.click();
  }catch(Exception e){
   /**If I remember correctly, it will be an ElementNotVisible or ElementNotClickable Exception.
   *
   *Here you can move the circle element, possibly using a drag and drop
   *method of the Actions class then click the element one more time.
   */
     actions.dragAndDropBy(circleElement, xOffset, yOffset).perform();
     button.click();
  }
}
```

**OR**

```
public boolean foo(){
  try{
     button.click();
     return true;
  }catch(Exception e){
     return false;
  }
}

public void bar(){
  if(!foo()){
     actions.dragAndDropBy(circleElement, xOffset, yOffset).perform();
     button.click();       
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Selenium can only replicate what a user can do. Realistically, user cannot interact with hidden elements. So, it is not possible to click on the hidden button without using javascript.

In case, if you want to use javascript:

> ```
> JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
> executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
> ```